# How to plot an impedance vs frequency graph in Proteus?

Tags: frequency, impedance, load, proteus, graph

I'm designing a circuit that simulates the impedance behavior of a real world speaker, which is not purely resistive and looks something like this:

[image]

I already got the basic circuit but need to tweak the resonant peaks and valleys and what not, so I need to plot an impedance vs frequency graph but I haven't been able to find how, I put a voltage probe as seen in the image below and the db vs freq. graph seems about right although inverted so I guess the probe should go there, however when I tried to put a current probe in different places I got different errors running the graph, **where should I put it?**

For the impedance part I searched online and found hints to the Add Trace command, but I've never used it before nor could I find tutorials or info about it, **how does it work?** I assume I should input the voltage probe as P1 and the current probe as P2 and then for the expression P1/P2 to get ohms??

**Thanks in advance for your help :)**

Here's my basic circuit:

[image]

Comment: Try driving your network with a 1 A A.C. current source, and plot the voltage across the input port.

Comment: I used "csource".What do I use as reference for the frequency graph?

Comment: You are probably suffering from low current signal at resonance, but this filter is the not conjugate of the speaker to flatten the response.